# Linq query to find average time difference per group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable that I want to query to get the average time difference per groups of Case ID.  My data looks as follows.

```
 Name     Case ID    Incept Time                  Edit Time
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Blue        1       2017-02-26T02:35:49-04:00    2017-03-26T02:35:49-04:00
 Blue        1       2017-02-26T02:34:49-04:00    2017-04-26T02:35:49-04:00
 Blue        1       2017-02-26T02:33:49-04:00    2017-05-26T02:35:49-04:00
 Blue        2       2017-02-26T02:32:49-04:00    2017-06-26T02:35:49-04:00
 Blue        2       2017-02-26T02:31:49-04:00    2017-07-26T01:35:49-04:00
 Blue        2       2017-02-26T02:30:49-04:00    2017-08-26T03:35:49-04:00
 Red         5       2017-02-26T02:25:49-04:00    2017-09-26T04:35:49-04:00
 Red         5       2017-02-26T02:15:49-04:00    2017-10-26T05:35:49-04:00
 Red         1       2017-02-26T02:05:49-04:00    2017-11-26T02635:49-04:00
 Red         1       2017-02-26T01:35:49-04:00    2017-12-26T02:35:49-04:00
 Red         5       2017-02-26T05:35:49-04:00    2017-12-27T02:35:49-04:00
```

So far I have the following query which can get into each group of Case ID and get the min and max values.

```
private IEnumerable<DataRow> _data;

var query = 
    from data in this._data
    group data by data.Field<string>("Name") into groups
    select new
    {
        formName = groups.Key,

        caseDiffs = 
            from d in groups
            group d by d.Field<string>("Case ID") into grps
            select new
            {
                min = grps.Min(t => 
                    DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(t.Field<string>("Incept Time"), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                ),
                max = grps.Max(t => 
                    DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(t.Field<string>("Edit Time"), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                )
            }
    };
```

My questions are

1) is it possible to include the difference between the min and max values (per case ID group) to the query

2) At the end how can I get the averages calculated like the diagram below

[image]

Comment: Why are you getting the min and the max?  Shouldn't you get all the differences in time per CaseID, then average those differences?

Comment: @maccettura I'm not sure that would give the same result

Comment: As far as I know, if you want the "average time difference per group", you would take all time differences, then divide by total time differences.  So for example: Given 4 time differences (in seconds lets say): `4, 6, 5.5, 7`, your average time difference in seconds would be `4 + 6 + 5.5 + 7 / 4` which would be `5.625`.

Comment: @maccettura I think if I did that then at the end I would need to take the average of the averages per Case ID to get an average per Name, which is not what I want (i.e. don't want to end up averaging averages)

Comment: Sounds like you should maybe edit your question, because as its written it's not entirely clear what you want.

Comment: @erotavlas I'm not so hot on mathematics, and I don't understand what you want exactly; just give us the mathematical formula for your example and I'm sure we'll get you your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED to reflect your changed question...

I've split this into three separate queries so that you can read it more easily (you can combine if you want):

```
        //convert the data using a projection query
        var query1 = from data in _data
                     let inceptTime = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(data.Field<string>("Incept Time"), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                     let editTime = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(data.Field<string>("Edit Time"), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                     let difference = editTime - inceptTime
                     select new
                     {
                         name = data.Field<string>("Name"),
                         caseId = data.Field<string>("Case ID"),
                         inceptTime,
                         editTime,
                         difference
                     };

        //group by caseID (also by NAME, but that won't matter for this grouping and is needed in query3)
        var query2 = from data in query1
                     group data by new { data.caseId, data.name } into groups
                     let min = groups.Min(x => x.inceptTime)
                     let max = groups.Max(x => x.editTime)
                     select new
                     {
                         name = groups.Key.name,
                         caseId = groups.Key.caseId,
                         min,
                         max,
                         diff = max - min
                     };

        //now group by name
        var query3 = from data in query2
                     group data by new { data.name } into groups
                     select new
                     {
                         name = groups.Key.name,
                         minDiff = groups.Min(x => x.diff),
                         maxDiff = groups.Max(x => x.diff),
                         avgDiff = new TimeSpan((long)groups.Average(x => x.diff.Ticks)),
                     };
```

NOTE: The "edit time" for the 9th record is in an invalid format

Comment: updated question with a diagram, does it help in any way?

Comment: Yes - I've updated the answer to reflect the new information.  I believe this does what you are looking for.

Comment: I think its working.  I wasn't aware of let keyword which was part of my problem, thanks for showing how to do this.  But I added the average to the final answer - is it correct?

Comment: Yup - that's correct.  I adjusted your change slightly to cast back to TimeSpan to show that you could do that too, if you wanted (instead of using TotalMinutes)

Comment: Regarding this grouping - group data by new { data.caseId, data.name } into groups. Is that a grouping of multiple columns by anonymous type?  Like described here http://www.manojn.com/2009/06/group-by-multiple-columns-using-anonymous-types-in-linq-to-sql/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a few `let` variables in your LINQ query. About 3 more lines, in fact. Your grouping LINQ should look like this:

```
var query = 
    from data in this._data
    group data by data.Field<string>("Name") into groups
    select new
    {
        formName = groups.Key,

        caseDiffs = from d in groups group d by d.Field<string>("Case ID") into grps

        // three variables here, so that you can do the 
        // date math that you require!
        let minDt = caseGroup.Min(t => 
                DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(t.Field<string>("Incept Time"), 
                "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        let maxDt = grps.Max(t => 
                DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(t.Field<string>("Edit Time"), 
                "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        let diffInSecs = (maxDt - minDt).TotalSeconds

        select new
        {
            min = minDt,
            max = maxDt,
            diff = diffInSecs
        }
    };
```

Hope that helps!